# SSO SAML2 integration with spring boot and angular

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I hope you are doing all well;

I am currently developping an application with spring boot in backend (REST API) and Angular in frontend. I want to use SSO for authenticating users with SAML 2.0 (I have to use SAML 2 in my project).

I have configured an app with OKTA as IDP in my backend (which is working just fine), but I am struggling to understand how to make this work with the frontend (which in my case is Angular).

- Who should be the one to initiate the authentication process : backend or frontend ?
- Should I use any access token ?
- Could you please describe me the process to use ?

I really appreciate your help !

Regards

I want to make Saml2 SSO work with angular and spring boot REST API